# Microsoft.Net.Compilers v2.0.1 fails on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.

I updated the **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** NuGet package from v1.3.2 to v2.0.1.  Now, when I publish my ASP.NET project to Azure (as a Web Role), the instance fails to start.  It runs fine on my development machine.  I've tried publishing again and rebooting the Azure server.  If I back out the NuGetPackage update and publish then it runs fine.

The error message I get in the web browser when I navigate to the Azure instance is:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -532462766.


Show Detailed Compiler Output:


d:\windows\system32\inetsrv>F:\sitesroot\0\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\f3c9e41c\00851a93_d67cd201\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\9f86e886\44d37352_a5add201\sbs.Lib.Web.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\4a2de565\002bb890_d67cd201\System.Spatial.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\d0ee012e\38a2b70e_0a4fd101\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\4ce71e79\ca66910f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\f03c9276\000080d0_2691d201\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\16600a25\58e3140e_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\407fdda3\e5ff3f0e_0a4fd101\System.Web.Mvc.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\de282a3a\0047069f_d67cd201\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\9f48442a\00ff46fa_c250d201\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\93d0f9eb\5f352209_a245d201\libphonenumber.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\5149b456\00199852_6b6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\986c74c3\00bd0b2a_d366d101\FluentSendgrid.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\72467d4c\89042b0e_0a4fd101\System.Web.Razor.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\45c16d6f\00edc901_dffdd101\Twilio.Mvc.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\e6a94eb4\00d24259_d247d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\30e03bfc\8d131cb0_67e7d001\EntityFramework.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\1ae5723f\00523a46_2f8ed201\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\a796f446\e370420e_0a4fd101\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\2c1beb55\0026a1c5_488dd201\Twilio.AspNet.Common.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\2fb31f54\00a9c40a_b3ddd101\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\448635b9\320f0509_a245d201\Ciloci.Flee.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\623b940c\007c06f2_e72ed201\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\0d99b147\bcfdb00f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\2af703b2\4ac53f0e_0a4fd101\MarkdownDeep.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\391c3e17\00a10176_a752d201\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\d5a6c285\580a3b0e_0a4fd101\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\176b7660\001f4fea_d8c8d101\MvcPaging.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\b5521d6b\00dda451_f23ad001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\aa150dc6\faf7300e_0a4fd101\System.Web.Helpers.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\990ecd0b\84937d32_baa2d201\sbs.Lib.Cde.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\54d28361\0084fb84_3155d201\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\779f1979\c0063b0f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\2cceb5f4\6f23fe0e_0a4fd101\System.Web.Optimization.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\b694ca55\817c7d0f_069dd201\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\bd167a43\00a074d9_1550d201\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\dedc70d0\00247f34_9c9ed201\Braintree.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\c56d47cb\b3782db0_67e7d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\127024f9\0024dbbc_13acd201\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\db27bce2\00389db9_5baad201\Twilio.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\164a8e95\000e369c_fa50d201\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\0d9951c0\bed520a9_a9add201\Indigo.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\85772f1a\09da890e_0a4fd101\Antlr3.Runtime.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\f3c8ff91\00953adb_2691d201\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\6032bd01\004f6208_b3ddd101\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\7161f894\00649ad1_c392d201\SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\02db14ce\00a361e2_2691d201\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\8385a315\a5caac10_0a4fd101\RestSharp.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\ca2f15b4\0061582c_c350d201\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\1b34c20a\416d6907_a245d201\evohtmltopdf.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\8ce48bee\825ba00f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\dc3b965d\fa6fb176_8f84d101\Twilio.Twiml.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\52ad0cfb\484b2852_a5add201\sbs.Lib.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\e7dc9c7d\007e12a8_6ad9d101\protobuf-net.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\d1a35297\0026a1c5_488dd201\Twilio.AspNet.Mvc.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\6c1037f8\008e13cf_6523d201\NodaMoney.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\0130e5a0\00f01929_ced5d101\Humanizer.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\6956382a\3eff360e_0a4fd101\System.Web.WebPages.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\35d9d2dc\00199852_6b6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\bc39598b\00e4da9d_b050d201\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\5ff5ab5e\004baf55_d247d001\Microsoft.Owin.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\df44fe65\605f9e0f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\8c5c89dc\00ceb8b7_3b98d201\SendGrid.SmtpApi.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\64e0ab6c\00b74c7e_c250d201\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\eb5aecfe\00ff735a_d247d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\be4fd571\00df7c95_d67cd201\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\3ef95a06\00eaa5ad_1650d201\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\dc6cdcae\4a0e7010_0a4fd101\WebGrease.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\a6a530b3\008f0832_dcc1cd01\Owin.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\c2c15ff6\003e2f6d_b9a1d201\SendGrid.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\fc7b6172\f696960f_0a4fd101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\a434366a\b112530e_0a4fd101\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel.dll"
 /R:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\assembly\dl3\4b1c2a24\0061582c_c350d201\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll" /out:"D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\App_Code.9jmewsuw.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\App_Code.9jmewsuw.0.cs" "D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\App_Code.9jmewsuw.1.cs" "D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3653c9f4\8117b1a3\App_Code.9jmewsuw.2.cs"
```

Comment: What version of .NET is installed on the server: 4.5.2 or 4.6+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this could be occurring is the server is running .NET 4.5.2.  The minimum required runtime changed between the 1.X and 2.X versions of Roslyn from 4.5.2 to 4.6. This exception is representative of running a 2.X version of Roslyn on 4.5.2.

The change here was deliberate but unfortunately we forgot to add a minimum required runtime entry into our app.config.  This means instead of a declarative error about the wrong runtime, we get an unhandled exception of this sort.  Sorry about that.  The following PR adds the appropriate entry and it will be present int the next release of our package

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/18018

Comment: Oh crud! Given the glacial pace that Azure servers support new versions of the .NET framework, it looks like I'm stuck at the old version of Roslyn for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Ok, after a bit more digging... According to the [Azure Guest OS Compatibility Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix) Family 5 supports 4.6. Family 4 does not. Time to tweak my cscfg files.

Answer (score 0):

-532462766 or 0xE0434352 hex means unknown software exception.  This could be due to many things, including an unhandled exception or a CLR runtime failure (like a bad executable).  In the case of an unhandled exception, I'd suggest adding more exception handling to see if you can catch it.  Otherwise, I'd either try to duplicate outside of azure so you can do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when deploying to an IIS server internally.  Rolling back the Compiler to v1.3.2 removed the error.  The updated compiler runs locally but not remotely, suggesting a dependency that does not exist on the server.  Smells like a bug to me.  I'll submit something to the Roslyn team and link this thread.  Maybe someone there knows more.  In the meantime, rolling back doesn't seem to have any negative side affects.

also:  see nugget issue 18533 
github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18533

The github issue was updated with " The 2.0 version of the compiler requires 4.6 and higher in order to run. This requirement was accidentally left off of our RTM config and hence produces exceptions vs. an explicit message. This was recently fixed though and will be a part of the next release."